# Make Google recognize my mobile site

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console, mobile, googlebot-mobile

We have our normal website - `http://www.example.com`.  We now also have a mobile site - `http://m.example.com`.  If a "mobile" user visits my site, we have JavaScript that detects it and auto forwards them over to the mobile site as well, for proper user experience.

When I use [Google's "Am I mobile friendly" tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/mobile-friendly/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww2.gwcwarranty.com%2F), my site doesn't show up as mobile friendly, since it's checking the original site, rather than what is redirected.

How do I "tell" Google, or assure myself that Google is aware of our mobile presence (since not having a mobile presence can affect SEO)?

Comment: Seems like using JavaScript to trigger a mobile switch would be a major speed/performance hit, as well as not too reliable/compatible in regards to automated tools/bots/scans. Are you able to migrate the trigger to server side pre-process instead?

Comment: And to confirm Google sees the mobile: find your site in a serp using a mobile phone. It will show a grey "mobile friendly" tag in the description. Might take a few days to aappear.

Comment: Thanks @dhaupin I never gave any thought to redirecting at the server side, but that would definately be a preferred option.  I'll research some more..

Answer (score 1):

This is what Google calls the "separate URLs" configuration.

In the desktop site, you should add a special `<link rel="alternate" ...>` tag pointing to the corresponding mobile URL. This helps Googlebot discover the location of your site's mobile pages.

In the mobile site, you should add a `<link rel="canonical" ...>` tag pointing to the corresponding desktop URL.

You can put the links either in the HTML of the pages or in your sitemaps.

More details and explanation [here](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/mobile-sites/mobile-seo/configurations/separate-urls).

Comment: As a note, those meta directives should happen with server side logic, don't use JS conditionals to render them into Dom via the existing JS mobile switch

Comment: Thanks!  Will add this today and let you know if I have any issues, much appreciated